# How Do I get the endpoint of an eventhub instance via PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that will create a new event hub, consumer group, and Shared Access Policies, all so I can then create an Event Grid Subscription that then uses the event hub as the endpoint.
Using:

```
$eventHubResource = New-AzureRmEventHub 
-ResourceGroupName $RG.Name 
-NamespaceName $eventHubNameSpace.Name 
-Name $eventHubName 
-MessageRetentionInDays $eventHubMessageRetention 
-PartitionCount $eventHubPartitionCount
```

I can create the event hub, SAP's and consumer groups, but when trying to create the EventGridSubscription using:
    New-AzureRmEventGridSubscription

it asks for an -Endpoint parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.eventgrid/new-azurermeventgridsubscription?view=azurermps-6.13.0

```
    -Endpoint
    Event subscription destination endpoint. This can be a webhook URL or the Azure resource ID of an EventHub.
```

How can I get the EventHub resource Id via powershell?

Get-AzureRmEventHub does not return the resource id to be used
New-AzureRmEventHub seems to return the same object as the Get-AzureRmEventHub

I haven't had any success with Get-AzureRmResource as it seems to only list the resources from a parent level and not for a given resource itself, but I may be using it incorrectly.

I'm open to suggestions on what to try.

Comment: This may be because of how you formatted your command. Try using backticks (`) at the end of each line if the command continues to the next line

Comment: If this is in regards to the New-AzureRmEventHub command, they are just on separate lines for readability, it's all one line when executed.  If not can you elaborate further?

Comment: [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) the params might help

Comment: [runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution) for azure

Comment: @lloyd I did a cursory glance of the links you provided and I'm not entirely sure how that might help get the resource id of an azure event hub?  Did I miss something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `New-AzureRmEventHub`, `Get-AzureRmEventHub`, `Get-AzureRmResource` all return the `resource ID`, refer to the command as below.

**Note**: My sample uses the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-2.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-1.0.0) powershell module, you can also the old `AzureRm` command.

```
$event = New-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -NamespaceName "joyeventhub" -Name "joyevent1"
$event.Id
$event | ConvertTo-Json
```

You could check the resource ID with `$event | ConvertTo-Json`,  `$event.Id` is the `resource ID` you want.

[image]

Then use the command to create the Event Grid Subscription

```
New-AzEventGridSubscription -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -EventSubscriptionName EventSubscription1 -EndpointType "eventhub" -Endpoint $event.Id
```

[image]

---

**Besides**, if you want to get the `resource ID` via `Get-AzEventHub` and `Get-AzResource`, refer to the commands as below.

```
#use Get-AzEventHub 
$id = (Get-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -NamespaceName "joyeventhub" -Name "joyevent").Id
#use Get-AzResource
$id = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -ResourceType "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs" -ResourceName "<NamespaceName>/<InstanceName>" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01).ResourceId
```

Comment: This is great!  I was missing the "$event.Id" portion and only spent 5 hours banging my head on my desk trying to figure this out.  This is the answer I was looking for.